# В unity3d лучше использовать на обьекте один скрипт, но "длинный", или несколько "маленьких"?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Интересует именно с точки зрения оптимизации. Порылся на официальном юнити, но там вещи посерьезнее предлагают оптимизировать

Comment: ИМХО 1 длинный. Но профайлер точнее скажет.

Comment: А что значит один скрипт, но “длинный”, или несколько “маленьких”? Если имеете в виду что у вас в одном скрипте и управление и физика и взаимодействие с врагами и начисление очков и пр - это конечно неправильно..надо разделять.Если у вас есть скрипт, к примеру `character controller` и он просто сам по себе не может быть маленьким - то и пусть будет. Один файл должен отражать суть его названия по факту и ничего лишнего и нет смысла делить. Обычно делают некие абстрактные классы с базовой реализацией, интерфейсы и пр. А в основных скриптах наследуются от них. В результате много всего экономится.

Comment: Да вообще понятие длинный/маленький размытое..... Кто-то считает 200 строк уже гигантом, а кто-то и 5000 нормальным

Comment: Мм, например, "длинный" скрипт - в нем объект и создаётся, и уничтожается. А два "маленьких" - в одном создаётся, а в другом уничтожается. А интересует то, какой вариант быстрее работает. Не берём в расчёт "понятность" названия - тут и так можно понятно назвать, и так. Но какой оптимальнее с точки зрения быстродействия? Вроде как многофункциональный должен лучше работать, но кто его знает...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Несколько лет назад занимался системами учета, работал в частности с Microsoft Dynamics AX. Там был свод правил Best Practics которые каждый уважающий себя программист старался соблюдать. Там конечно несколько иначе выглядит работа с объектами, своя специфика, но правила хорошие. Если метод не умещается на одной странице, значит метод следует дробить. Каждый объект, а в нем метод должен выполнять атомарную задачу, а смысл действия должен быть понятен из имени. Если вы чувствуете что ваша компонента перегружена и помимо того что следит как человек бегает она еще и реплики в квестах сочиняет и на сервер данные отправляет то явно что-то не то с архитектурой решения.

За всех не скажу, а я стараюсь делать так. У меня есть задача получить управление от пользователя, есть задача сдвинуть персонажа. Я делаю для каждой задачи свою компоненту. Надо будет потом мне обездвижить персонажа я выключу компоненту с управлением от игрока и вуаля. Берем задачу и решаем на сколько она сложная, а там уже по своему усмотрению делить. Главное не переусердствовать.